# Pull node attribute out aswell as node value from td element

Tags: php, html

I have the below PHP code that gets a HTML file and pulls the table out of it, next the table is parsed and the cell data is returned fine like in `Current Output`, I'm trying to get the href attribute output also like in the `Desired Output` snippet, I can't see how to target just the href from the cell if a href exists, I only seem to be able to get the node value, any help greatly appreciated.

**Current Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 213
            [url] => Website
        )
)
```

**Desired Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 213
            [url] => Website
            [link] => example.com/page/1/
        )
)
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>213</td>
        <td><a href="example.com/page/1/">Website</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**PHP**

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$html = $dom->loadHTMLFile($url);

$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');
$rows = $tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr');
$cols = $rows->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('th');
$row_headers = null;

foreach($cols AS $node) {
    $row_headers[] = $node->nodeValue;
}

$table = array();
$rows = $tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr');
foreach($rows AS $row) {
    $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
    $row = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach($cols AS $node) {
        if ($row_headers != null) {
            $row[$row_headers[$i]] = $node->nodeValue;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    if (!empty($row)) {
        $table[] = $row;
    }
}
```

I had tried `$row['link'] = $node->getAttribute('href');` in the nested foreach `foreach($cols AS $node)` but it didn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the code below and the inline comments

```
$html = '<table>
    <tr>
        <td>213</td>
        <td><a href="example.com/page/1/">Website</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>444</td>
        <td><a href="example.org/page/1/">not a website</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$html = $dom->loadHTML($html);

$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$rows = $dom->getElementsByTagName("tr");

foreach($rows as $row){

    $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td'); 

    $id = $cols->item(0)->nodeValue; // get the id, the first td element, index=0
    $anchor = $cols->item(1)->nodeValue; // get the anchor text, the second td element, index=1
    $url    = $cols->item(1)->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->getAttribute('href'); // get the url from the href attribute, the second td element, index=1

    $result[] = array(
        'id' => $id,
        'anchor'=> $anchor,
        'url'=>$url
    );
}

print_r($result);
```

should output this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 213
            [anchor] => Website
            [url] => example.com/page/1/
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 444
            [anchor] => not a website
            [url] => example.org/page/1/
        )

)
```